# Java Simple Class to Return a Reversed Singly Linked List

Tags: java, list, hyperlink, reverse

I am trying to write a simple class that reverse a **singly linked list** and return a **constructed linked list**. The code below is working if i make everything public which I dont want to. Anybody interested to address my question? (should I use doubly linked list? or it is possible with single link list?)

What I want is a function `reverseList` receives a `ListNode Object` return a `ListNode Object` (in reverse order).  Like this:

```
originalNumber=OriginalNumber.reverseList();
```

//// my code

```
public class ReverseLinkList {

    public static ListNode originalNumber=new ListNode();
    public static ListNode reversedNumber=new ListNode();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create 1->2->3->null
        originalNumber.add(1);originalNumber.add(2);originalNumber.add(3);
        System.out.print(num1.toString()+"\n");

        //create 3->2->1->null
        reversedNumber=originalNumber.reverseList;

    }


}

class ListNode{ 
    private class Node{
        Object data;
        Node next;
        Node(int v){
            data=v;
            next=null;
        }
        public Object getData(){
            return data;
        }
        public void setData(int v){
            data=v;
        }
        public Node getNext(){
            return next;
        }
        public void setNext(Node nextValue){
            next=nextValue;
        }
    }

    private Node head;
    public void add(int data){
        if(head==null){
            head=new Node(data);
        }
        Node temp=new Node(data);
        Node current=head;
        if(current !=null){
            while(current.getNext()!=null){
                current=current.getNext();
            }
            current.setNext(temp);
        }
    }
    public String toString(){
        String output="";
        if(head!=null){
            Node current=head.getNext();
            while(current!=null){
                //System.out.println(output);
                output+=current.getData().toString();
                current=current.getNext();
            }
        }
        return output;      
    }
    public Node getHead(){
        return head;
    }

    public static Node reverse(Node node) {
        Node prev = null;
        Node current = node;
        Node next = null;
        while (current != null) {
            next = current.next;
            current.next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = next;
        }
        node = prev;
        return node;
    }

}
```

---

### The original and working code which I do not want

```
public class ReversedLinkedList {
    static Node head;
    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d) {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }
    Node reverse(Node node) {
        Node prev = null;
        Node current = node;
        Node next = null;
        while (current != null) {
            next = current.next;
            current.next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = next;
        }
        node = prev;
        return node;
    }
    void printList(Node node) {
        while (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + "");
            node = node.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReversedLinkedList list = new ReversedLinkedList();
        list.head = new Node(1);
        list.head.next = new Node(2);
        list.head.next.next = new Node(3);

        list.printList(head);
        head = list.reverse(head);
        System.out.println("");
        list.printList(head);

    }
}
```

Comment: "...i make everything public which I dont want to", what you mean?

Comment: you need a doubly linked list

Comment: @cainiaofei i am going to update the question to add the working code

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You can make the member variables private & use the appropriate getters & setters:

```
public ListNode reverseList() {
    Node prev = null;
    Node current = this.getHead();
    Node next = null;
    while (current != null) {
        next = current.next;
        current.next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    head = prev;
    return this;
}
```

This allows you print a reversed list:

```
System.out.println(originalNumber.reverseList());
```

Note that the `originalNumber` is itself manipulated. So, subsequent prints (`System.out.println(originalNumber);`) would still print the reversed list.

If you don't want the original to be modified, then there really isn't any other way apart from collecting all the data & then looping through in the reverse order & adding them into a new list:

```
public ListNode reverseList() {
    int size = 0;

    // Calculate size
    Node current = this.getHead();
    while (current != null) {
        size++;
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    int[] data = new int[size];

    // Collect all data
    current = this.getHead();
    int index = 0;
    while (current != null) {
        data[index++] = current.getData();
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    // Add to a new list in reverse order
    ListNode reversed = new ListNode();
    for (index = size - 1; index >= 0; index--)
        reversed.add(data[index]);
    return reversed;
}
```

That first scan to get the size can be skipped if size is tracked while adding elements to the list or by simply switching to an `ArrayList` instead of an array for `data`.

Finally there's the elegant recursive approach which also keeps the original `ListNode` intact:

```
public ListNode reverseRecursive() {
    return recursive(this.getHead());
}

private ListNode recursive(Node node) {
    if (node == null)
        return new ListNode();
    else {
        ListNode listNode = this.recursive(node.next);
        listNode.add(node.data);
        return listNode;
    }
}
```

To print:

```
System.out.println(originalNumber.reverseRecursive());
```

Here we needn't keep track of size & you make use of the call stack to naturally keep track & pop out the nodes in reverse.